# How would this Parallel.ForEach loop be done without using lambda expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

Trying to understand what using delegates in C# is like without lambda expressions. I understand their function, but still blurry on their syntax. What would this piece of code look like without using => lambda shortcut?

```
//pictureList is a string array of C:\Pictures\pic_1 through 10.jpeg file paths
Parallel.ForEach(pictureList, currentPic =>
 {
    string picName = Path.GetFileName(currentPic);
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(currentPic))
    {
         bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
         bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(newDir, picName));
    }
 }
);
```

Comment: A side note, the lambda code includes loading and saving the bitmap so make sure to profile this. The gains from going Parallel with that much I/O might be negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambda is not a "shortcut", it is a way to produce delegate objects "inline" (i.e. without defining a separate method).

You can use the old way of producing delegates inline (i.e. anonymous methods), like this

```
Parallel.ForEach(pictureList, delegate(Image currentPic) {
    ...
});
```

or define a separate method for it, like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(pictureList, ProcessPicture);
...
static void ProcessPicture(Image currentPic) {
    ...
}
```